# How to find site/web template title based on site url

Tags: development, sharepoint-server, site-template, web-template

I've applied a custom web template in a site.

How to retrieve the template title based on site url in c#?

FYI: My Custom Web Template name is "**{guid}#MyNewTemplate**" and title is "**MyNewTemplate**", basically it is a team site.

Note: I've also checked related questions in StackExchange but none worked for me to get the desired result, mostly it returns 'team site' title rather than my custom web template title

I would like to find the custom web template title. Please Help me out here

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use either;

```
SPWeb.WebTemplate
```

to get the Web Template **name**, or;

```
SPWeb.WebTemplateId
```

to get the Web Template **ID**

See the properties exposed by the SPWeb object on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb_properties.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. According to your suggestion, I will be getting only "STS#0" which is my basetemplate details. But I'm looking for custom template name and title.

Comment: This will give you the custom template name and title? "STS#0" is the template for a team site